# Why there are free proxy servers?

Tags: proxy, proxy-server

What is the owner's motivation to run a free proxy server? I'm talking about free direct anonymous IP proxies like 123.45.67.89:8888.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of the reasons that crossed my mind:

- steal your identity

  - because, your traffic is routed through their server. Any credential you use on internet can be intercepted by them.
- help his/her friends overcome country's blockade.
- just for fun (or learning)

Comment: Or IRC ban evading. What a nightmare.